# Why object does not snap?

Tags: snapping

Below is my setting but the building won't snap on the face of the ground.
[image]

Comment: Just a thought - Snapping can be counter-intuitive sometimes.... make sure you're placing the mouse cursor over the desired face when you move your object instead of trying to place the two faces together, if that makes any sense. It might look like you're dragging the midpoint of your object towards the desired face, but once your mouse hits it, it should snap and look properly "stacked".

Answer (score 3):

This should work.. strangely, the behaviour of Snap with these settings is view-dependent. In the orthogonal view parallel to the surface there's an ambiguity in 'Closest' that the system can't handle.  The snap is fine if you view from an angle, and just to make sure, constrain the move, too.. say... <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

while Im not 100% sure what it is, I can help you figure out some things. First, try adding in a cube and a plane. This will let you see if the cube will snap to the face of the plane. If not, try restarting blender or updating it. You can also try some of the other snap features. As well as trying them in edit mode. Hope this helps!